# Mathematics named after places

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list

Chinese Remainder Theorem is perhaps the most famous piece of mathematics named after a country. Another example, although less famous, is the concept of a Polish space. What other theorems, concepts or objects are named after a geographic region, a city or any other type of location?

Comment: Do the seven bridges of Königsberg and the St. Petersburg paradox count as regions?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_concepts_named_after_places) is a big list of mathematical concepts named after places.

Comment: An infamous example: [Chinese Dumbass Notation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h355856)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Haha, what an absurd name!

Comment: Here is a funny and probably just meant as a joke quote in a textbook I saw regarding Polish spaces: "The name seems to have arisen this way: the Poles decided that, being a small nation, they should concentrate their mathematical efforts in one area and do it well rather than spread themselves thin. They chose analysis, extending the achievements of the great Pole Banach. They excelled."

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: I realize this is not the right place to say this, but I'm not sure what the right place is: why is "Russian constructivism" on that list?

Comment: An interesting omission from the Wikipedia list is "Arabic numerals".  Perhaps because they don't actually seem to have originated in Arabia, or they're named after the cultural / ethnic group (Arabs) instead of the place (Arabia)?

Comment: @WillR You're right. It shouldn't be on the list. I am going to remove it. I read the linked article carefully first.

Comment: @WillR, I guess they just had the wrong link. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics))'s the correct one. Russian constructivism might be referring to the Russian school of constructivism (developed by [A.A. Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov_Jr.)).

Comment: Klein’s *Erlanger Program* doesn’t count, does it? I don’t remember where, but I once read that Erlangen is the most mentioned german city name in mathematics publications because of it.

Comment: Nobody mentioned the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Would the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) be accepted as an answer?

Comment: There's Hungarian (style) combinatorics.

Comment: Geometry - Earth measurement.

Comment: [A similar question on MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64617/mathematical-ideas-named-after-places)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Honestly, that should probably be an answer. It's pretty much as complete as could be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is already a Wikipedia page that could be found by a trivial Google search.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, because although it is trivial to answer, the stated closure reason (“off-topic” and “This question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center.”) are both misleading, and give the wrong impression to anyone who sees this question. If something like “does not show enough effort” is the real reason for closing the question, then that must be stated as the reason for closure.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Apparently you didn't read the "off-topic" reason at all. It includes "lacking context" and the advice is "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it." Furthermore, I stated explicitly the reason in a comment just before yours.

Comment: @user21820 I did not take a screenshot at the time, but I can assure you that anyone who visited this question would have seen “This question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center” which is not true. (This may be a limitation of the Stack Exchange software, but I consider such a message harmful and would rather have the question open than send out such misleading messages.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Ah okay it's a limitation of SE software, which shows the majority reason. Thanks for the response, but in any case in my opinion it's worse to have question on this site that show everyone that people do not need to put a single shred of effort into their question, and others will still serve them the answer on a silver platter.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR While it does say that, it also provides links to the places where it expands on what it means (which includes what user21820 has mentioned.)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The typical visitor to the question will not follow the links — they will instead see “off-topic” and “This question does not appear to be about math within the scope defined in the help center”.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Well, I'm not in charge of the way SE displays these things. All I'm saying is that if you cared enough, its there for you to follow through.

Answer (score 22):

There exists a list on Wikipedia about this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_concepts_named_after_places

Comment: This sounds like a convincing answer, but does it not fall foul of the _no link-only answer_ convention? It actually seems to me more useful than a series of answers naming one or two each!

Comment: @PJTraill, I guess it's not much of a problem in this case since this is a community wiki answer and the linked article is from a sufficiently reliable website and has negligible chances of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). If you notice, I mentioned the same link in the comments and didn't post it as an answer precisely because of the reason you mention though.

Comment: and yet, in 2021, it now points to a "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name." page.

Answer (score 21):

The [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), [Monte Carlo algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm), [Las Vegas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm), and [Atlantic City algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_City_algorithm) have an element of randomness in common.

Answer (score 12):

Does Manhattan norm ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm)) count as such?

Comment: There's also the [Metropolis algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), which I recognize was named after someone's surname, but it's also Superman's city :-)

Comment: I've also heard the discrete metric referred to as the Los Angeles metric: everything is 45 minutes away.

Comment: @Micah: I've heard that attributed to Stanislaw Ulam, with the distance being an hour.

Answer (score 12):

[Tropical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) was named in honor of the (Hungarian-)Brazilian mathematician Imre Simon.

Answer (score 10):

In mathematical finance, there is a convention of naming various styles of [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance)) after places.  American and European options are the most common, but I've also heard of:

- Asian options
- Russian options
- Bermuda, Canary, Verde options (partway between American and European)
- Boston options
- Parisian options

Comment: Monte Carlo simulation is one of my favorite mathematical methods named after a place, AND it is used for options pricing!

Answer (score 9):

[Berkeley cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Berkeley) are a type of large cardinal.

(And I guess one could argue about whether [worldly cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly) count.)

Comment: In the same vein, there are now Varsovian models.

Answer (score 8):

[**Steiner's Roman surface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_surface) is a continuous image of the real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^{3}.$ It has its name because the parametrization was discovered by [Jakob Steiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Steiner) while he was in **Rome** in 1844.

Comment: The Roman surface is **not** an embedding (nor an immersion) of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$.  It is, however, a continuous image of $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Thanks, I don't know much about it besides what I've read on the Wikipedia page, which is a bit confusingly written. Of course, I should have realised myself since it obviously self-intersects (and "embedding" is usually reseved for injections, no?).

Comment: The word "embedding" has a precise mathematical meaning: "homeomorphism onto its image."  In particular, yes, embeddings are injective.  (And yes, the Wikipedia article is definitely confusing as written.) Anyway, I think you mean the **parametrization** (or **mapping**) was discovered by Jakob Steiner.  (I'm not trying to nitpick; it's just that your wording is somewhat misleading.)

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Well, I think more generally we just mean "isomorphism onto its image", but yes.

Answer (score 7):

The famous [Königsberg Bridge Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg) certainly qualifies, and was the first that came to mind for me.

Answer (score 7):

The [SNCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNCF) metric has the property that to pass from point A to point B you have to pass via Paris.

Comment: Also known in the UK as the British Rail metric (same joke, with Paris replaced by London).

Answer (score 5):

The **Method of Four Russians** is a technique for speeding up algorithms involving Boolean matrices, or more generally algorithms involving matrices in which each cell may take on only a bounded number of possible values.

It is unclear whether all the four authors were in fact Russian at the moment of publishing the paper. It is known that at least two of the four authors (Arlazarov and Kronrod) were actually born in Moscow. While Kronrod died in Moscow in $1986$, Arlazarov still lives and works in Moscow as of $2016$.

Answer (score 4):

[Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) and [reverse Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) notation.

(Not to be confused with [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), which this is definitely the wrong SE site for.)

Answer (score 3):

What about mathematics created by mathematicians whose surnames were derived from names of cities? Would that count? If so, here are some examples:

- The [Győri-Lovász theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01474) was named after [Ervin Győri](https://www.renyi.hu/~ervin/) — Győr, Hungary.
- [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) was named after [Mojżesz Presburger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moj%C5%BCesz_Presburger) — *Pressburg* (Bratislava), Slovakia.
- Razborov-Smolensky polynomials were named after [Roman Smolensky](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=32415) — Smolensk, Russia.
- [Szegedy quantum walks](http://arxiv.org:443/find/all/1/ti:+Szegedy/0/1/0/all/0/1) were named after [Mario Szegedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Szegedy) — Szeged, Hungary.
- [Wiener processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) were named after [Norbert Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener) — *Wien* (Vienna), Austria.

Comment: Not exactly the thing the question is asking for, but interesting piece of trivia nonetheless. One reason why it would be problematic to include such examples is that it's hard to see where to draw the line.
Should Barry Mazur qualify? Mazur is a common Polish surname, meaning literally "a guy from Masuria". I have no idea if he even set foot in Masuria, nor am I even sure he has Polish ancestors...

Comment: @JakubKonieczny There's also [Stanisław Mazur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanisław_Mazur). I thought of including Mazur in my list, but, indeed, it is too common. Wiener is also somewhat common, but Presburger seems to be much less common.

Comment: This immediately made me think of the Cremona group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group . When I first heard about it, I thought it was indeed named directly after the town; and I spent quite some time wondering if there was any kind of connection between violin-making and birational transformations...

Comment: The Wiener sausage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_sausage) is clearly named after both Wiener (the man) and Wiener (the sausage).

Answer (score 3):

The [Wonderful Demlo numbers](https://oeis.org/A002477) were named by [D. R. Kaprekar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._R._Kaprekar#Demlo_number) for an Indian train station.

(Where is that town/station? What are its geographical coordinates, and does it still exist today?)

Answer (score 2):

The word  *algorithm* is derived, through medieval Latin from [Khiva](http://www.khiva.info/display.php?site=khiva&page=tour/othersights/alkh&lang=en) (Uzbekistan). The 9th-century mathematician Abū Ja‘far Muhammad ibn Mūsa, author of   works on algebra and arithmetic, was called al-Ḵwārizmī ‘the man of Ḵwārizm’. In fact, *algebra* is a term form medicine used in one of his books *Hisab al-jabr w'al-muqabala*.

His name entered the language (influenced by Greek arithmos ‘number’) through Old French from medieval Latin algorismus. He is depicted below.

[image: al-Ḵwārizmī ‘the man of Ḵwārizm']

As far as I known, the concept of algorithm derived from his (first?) complete solution to the second degree equation, divided in six different cases, taking into account that dealing with negative numbers and the zero was not natural at that time.

Aside, the polar co-ordinate  system seems [the most obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). And yes, we have two poles. The exact origin is not clear to me. However, the [Polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), used in astronomy in ancient times, was slowly extended into a genuine coordinate system, related to the poles

> The calculation is essentially the conversion of the equatorial polar
>   coordinates of Mecca (i.e. its longitude and latitude) to its polar
>   coordinates (i.e. its qibla and distance) relative to a system whose
>   reference meridian is the great circle through the given location and
>   the Earth's poles, and whose polar axis is the line through the
>   location and its antipodal point.

Comment: Are you sure polar coordinate is named after north/south poles ?